# How do I use a recursive procedure in a loop in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, recursion

I have an employees table with demographics data. This table has two fields I need: Employee ID and Manager ID. I need to build a join table that would look like this:

<kbd>Employee ID</kbd><kbd>Manager ID</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>3</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>4</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>                 <kbd>3</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>                 <kbd>4</kbd>

So I need the join table to show, for each employee, all the people above them. In case of employee 1 his direct manager is 2, his manager's manager is 3 and his manager's manager's manager is 4.

I have a MySQL procedure that seems to be working when called for an employee:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE chainReaction (IN employee_id int, IN orig_id int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE manager_id int default NULL;
    SET @@SESSION.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    SELECT ManagerID 
    INTO manager_id 
    FROM employees
    WHERE EmployeeID = employee_id;
    IF( manager_id is not null) THEN
        INSERT INTO joinTable(EmpID, SupID) VALUES(
            orig_id,manager_id
        );
        CALL chainReaction(manager_id, orig_id);
  end if;
END;
```

Problem 1: 
When calling chainReaction it looks like I need to provide the employee ID twice to the procedure because otherwise the original employee ID is 'lost' and the resulting inserts for employee 1 look like this:

<kbd>Employee ID</kbd><kbd>Manager ID</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>                 <kbd>3</kbd>
<kbd>4</kbd>                 <kbd>4</kbd>

So the Employee ID doesn't stay fixed to 1 as I needed it. Again, this procedure works when called as it is now: chainReaction(1,1);

But here's problem 2:

I have some code to loop through all rows in the employee table and call chainReaction on them:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RowPerRow ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE n int default 0;
    DECLARE i int default 0;
    DECLARE employee_id int default null;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees INTO n;
    SET i=0;
    WHILE i<n DO
        SELECT EmployeeID FROM employees WHERE LIMIT i,1 INTO employee_id;
        CALL chainReaction(employee_id,employee_id);
    END WHILE;
END;
```

The problem is that if I call this RowPerRow() procedure the employee column in the join table is stuck to the first employee ID no matter what row is being processed.

Comment: Don't. Search for hierarchical queries instead - the paren/children problem is well understood with many solutions that use a database's strengths. Databases can query sets of data very quickly, using indexes to *minimize* the number of IO operations required. Recursion, loops and cursors on the other hand are the slowest way to search, reading rows one by one. Check eg [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: I googled this problem up and down. What I learned is that MySQL doesn't do recursive selects. I've seen your link previously and the first example works when you have a determined depth (4 level in that case) or you have to do the whole left/right thing which I don't believe would work on large data sets. How would you figure the left/right values for 10000 employees?

Comment: Read the rest of the article before dismissing it. The nested set solution is one of the best methods and works for arbitrary depths. The result is a simple range query on a pair of *indexed* columns. I've used it to query millions of records of arbitrary depth.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it but how did they determine the Left/Right values beforehand? In the example he just inserts them from the get go and then does the queries. I can't print out a chart and manually start counting the values for 10000 employees.

Comment: They don't. The values are determined when a node is inserted/removed. The article includes the statements needed to add/remove nodes in the `Add New Nodes` and `Deleting Nodes` section. Before you ask, converting the current hierarchy model (adjacency list) to a nested set is also covered in the references and many online articles

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my procedures work just fine, what I was missing in the RowPerRow procedure is incrementing the counter (SET i = i + 1;). Here's the code fixed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RowPerRow ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE n int default 0;
    DECLARE i int default 0;
    DECLARE employee_id int default null;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees INTO n;
    SET i=0;
    WHILE i<n DO
        SELECT EmployeeID FROM employees WHERE LIMIT i,1 INTO employee_id;
        CALL chainReaction(employee_id,employee_id);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
```